# KOTLIN 2 Dice with 2 buttons, compare the result and see which one is higher

Tags: kotlin

HELP; I have two dice with two buttons, when pressed respectively, each one shows an image (which is one of its faces), my idea is to associate a value to each face of the dice to then compare both results and choose which one is higher, but being inside the "setOnClickListener", I can't find the way to get that value to be able to work from the same activity. Any solution ???

```
class PaginaCombate2v2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var btnJugador1: ImageView
    lateinit var btnJugador2: ImageView
    lateinit var dadoJugador1: ImageView
    lateinit var dadoJugador2: ImageView
    var imagenDadoJ1: Int = 0
    var imagenDadoJ2: Int = 0

    private var guardarColorJ1: String = ""
    var guardarColorJ2: String = ""

    var resultJugador1: Int = 0
    var resultJugador2: Int = 0
    var resultadoJ1J2: Int = 0

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pagina_combate2v2)

        // Migramos datos
        val bundle2 = intent.extras
        val idJugadoresCombate = bundle2?.getIntegerArrayList("combatir_id")
        val arrayJugadores = bundle2?.getIntegerArrayList("arrayJugadores")
        val intent = intent
        val dataBaseJugadores: EstadisticasInicialesJugadores? =
            intent.getSerializableExtra("dataBaseJugadores") as EstadisticasInicialesJugadores?

        println("\n ESTE ES EL arrayJugadores: $arrayJugadores")
        println("esto es idJugadoresCombate: $idJugadoresCombate")
        // JUGADOR 1
        val n1J1 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ1N1)
        val n1J2 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ1N2)
        val n1J3 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ1N3)
        val n1J4 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ1N4)
        val n1J5 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ1N5)
        val n1J6 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ1N6)
        val n1J7 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ1N7)
        val n1J8 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ1N8)
        val n1J9 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ1N9)
        val n1J10 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ1N10)
        val n1J11 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ1N11)
        val n1J12 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ1N12)
        // JUGADOR 2
        val n2J1 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ2N1)
        val n2J2 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ2N2)
        val n2J3 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ2N3)
        val n2J4 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ2N4)
        val n2J5 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ2N5)
        val n2J6 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ2N6)
        val n2J7 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ2N7)
        val n2J8 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ2N8)
        val n2J9 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ2N9)
        val n2J10 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ2N10)
        val n2J11 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ2N11)
        val n2J12 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagenJ2N12)

        val diccRelacionJugadorConFotoPerfilJ1: Map<ImageView, Int?> = mapOf(
            n1J1 to arrayJugadores?.get(0),
            n1J2 to arrayJugadores?.get(1),
            n1J3 to arrayJugadores?.get(2),
            n1J4 to arrayJugadores?.get(3),
            n1J5 to arrayJugadores?.get(4),
            n1J6 to arrayJugadores?.get(5),
            n1J7 to arrayJugadores?.get(6),
            n1J8 to arrayJugadores?.get(7),
            n1J9 to arrayJugadores?.get(8),
            n1J10 to arrayJugadores?.get(9),
            n1J11 to arrayJugadores?.get(10),
            n1J12 to arrayJugadores?.get(11),
        )

        val diccRelacionJugadorConFotoPerfilJ2: Map<ImageView, Int?> = mapOf(
            n2J1 to arrayJugadores?.get(0),
            n2J2 to arrayJugadores?.get(1),
            n2J3 to arrayJugadores?.get(2),
            n2J4 to arrayJugadores?.get(3),
            n2J5 to arrayJugadores?.get(4),
            n2J6 to arrayJugadores?.get(5),
            n2J7 to arrayJugadores?.get(6),
            n2J8 to arrayJugadores?.get(7),
            n2J9 to arrayJugadores?.get(8),
            n2J10 to arrayJugadores?.get(9),
            n2J11 to arrayJugadores?.get(10),
            n2J12 to arrayJugadores?.get(11),
        )

        val relacionDiccionarioJugadoresConIdJugadores: Map<Map<String, Int>, Int> = mapOf(
            dataBaseJugadores!!.gawainEIJ to arrayJugadores!!.get(0),
            dataBaseJugadores!!.ragnellEIJ to arrayJugadores!!.get(1),
            dataBaseJugadores!!.mordredEIJ to arrayJugadores!!.get(2),
            dataBaseJugadores!!.culhwchEIJ to arrayJugadores!!.get(3),
            dataBaseJugadores!!.olwenEIJ to arrayJugadores!!.get(4),
            dataBaseJugadores!!.percivalEIJ to arrayJugadores!!.get(5),
            dataBaseJugadores!!.lancelotEIJ to arrayJugadores!!.get(6),
            dataBaseJugadores!!.nimueEIJ to arrayJugadores!!.get(7),
            dataBaseJugadores!!.yvainEIJ to arrayJugadores!!.get(8),
            dataBaseJugadores!!.elaineEIJ to arrayJugadores!!.get(9),
            dataBaseJugadores!!.sirKayEIJ to arrayJugadores!!.get(10),
            dataBaseJugadores!!.ginebraEIJ to arrayJugadores!!.get(11),
        )

        for (i in diccRelacionJugadorConFotoPerfilJ1) {
            if (i.value == idJugadoresCombate?.get(0)) {
                i.key.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }

        for (i in diccRelacionJugadorConFotoPerfilJ2) {
            if (i.value == idJugadoresCombate?.get(1)) {
                i.key.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }

        // PARTE DEL AZAR
        btnJugador1 = findViewById(R.id.btnJ1)
        btnJugador2 = findViewById(R.id.btnJ2)
        dadoJugador1 = findViewById(R.id.dadoJ1)
        dadoJugador2 = findViewById(R.id.dadoJ2)
        val arrayBtnJugadores: ArrayList<ImageView> = arrayListOf(btnJugador1,btnJugador2)

        val diccDadoIDColor: Map<Int, String> = mapOf(
            R.drawable.d1 to "rojo",
            R.drawable.d2 to "azul",
            R.drawable.d3 to "naranja",
            R.drawable.d4 to "lila",
            R.drawable.d5 to "negro",
            R.drawable.d6 to "verde",
        )

        var j2ResultadoDeFuncion1: Int = 0
        btnJugador1.setOnClickListener {
            println("---BOTON 2---")
            val randomJugador1: Int = (1..6).random()
            imagenDadoJ1 = when (randomJugador1) {
                1 -> R.drawable.d1
                2 -> R.drawable.d2
                3 -> R.drawable.d3
                4 -> R.drawable.d4
                5 -> R.drawable.d5
                else -> {
                    R.drawable.d6
                }
            }
            dadoJugador1.setImageResource(imagenDadoJ1)
            j2ResultadoDeFuncion1 = pruebaNumero1(
                diccDadoIDColor,
                relacionDiccionarioJugadoresConIdJugadores,
                idJugadoresCombate!!.get(0),
                imagenDadoJ1,
                guardarColorJ1,
                btnJugador1,
                resultJugador1
            )
            guardarValor(j2ResultadoDeFuncion1)

        }
        
        var j2ResultadoDeFuncion2: Int = 0
        btnJugador2.setOnClickListener {
            println("---BOTON 2---")
            val randomJugador2: Int = (1..6).random()
            imagenDadoJ2 = when (randomJugador2) {
                1 -> R.drawable.d1
                2 -> R.drawable.d2
                3 -> R.drawable.d3
                4 -> R.drawable.d4
                5 -> R.drawable.d5
                else -> {
                    R.drawable.d6
                }
            }
            dadoJugador2.setImageResource(imagenDadoJ2)
            j2ResultadoDeFuncion2 = pruebaNumero1(
                diccDadoIDColor,
                relacionDiccionarioJugadoresConIdJugadores,
                idJugadoresCombate!!.get(1),
                imagenDadoJ2,
                guardarColorJ2,
                btnJugador2,
                resultJugador2
            )
            guardarValor(j2ResultadoDeFuncion2)

        }

        val resultJugadorSuma = j2ResultadoDeFuncion2
        println("LONGA "+resultJugadorSuma)
        }




    fun pruebaNumero1(
        diccDadoIDColor: Map<Int, String>, relacionDiccionarioJugadoresConIdJugadores: Map<Map<String, Int>, Int>,
        idJugadoresCombate: Int,
        imagenDadoJ: Int,
        guardarColorJ: String,
        btnJugador: ImageView,
        resultJugador:Int
    ): Int {
        var guardarColorJ: String = ""
        var resultJugador: Int = 0

        for (k in diccDadoIDColor){
            if(imagenDadoJ == k.key){
                println("EL COLOR ES ${k.value}")
                guardarColorJ = k.value
                println("se ha añadido el color, ahora es: $guardarColorJ")
                if(guardarColorJ != ""){btnJugador.visibility = View.INVISIBLE}
            }
        }
        for (i in relacionDiccionarioJugadoresConIdJugadores){
            if(i.value == idJugadoresCombate){
                for (j in i.key){
                    if(guardarColorJ == j.key){
                        println("EL COLOR ${guardarColorJ}, TIENE EL VALOR ${j.value}, EN EL JUGADOR CON LA ID ${idJugadoresCombate}")
                        resultJugador = j.value
                        println("se ha añadido el valor del color $guardarColorJ: $resultJugador")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return resultJugador
    }

    fun guardarValor(valor: Int): Int{
        var valorReturn: Int = 0
        return valorReturn
    }

    fun sumarDosValors(valor1:Int, valor2: Int): Int{
        var resultSumaDosValores: Int = 0

        println("Se van a sumar ${valor1} + $valor2")
        resultSumaDosValores = valor1 + valor2
        println("Se van a sumar ${valor1} + $valor2")


        return resultSumaDosValores
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest that you break this into smaller peaces with some explanation. Trying to understand your current code with non-English names will just take too long time for most of us. BR

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.